# pivot in sql server 2012 with uniqeness

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

if i have a table like given below.

```
declare @mytble table
(
orders int,
product varchar (50),
quantity int

)

INSERT @mytble

SELECT 100,'CUP','1' UNION ALL
SELECT 100, 'PLATE',2 UNION ALL
SELECT 101,'CUP','1' UNION ALL
SELECT 102,'CUP','2' UNION ALL
SELECT 103, 'CUP',1 UNION ALL
SELECT 103,'PLATE','3' UNION ALL
SELECT 103,'GLASS','1' 

SELECT * FROM @mytble
```

will it be possible to get output like this.

[image]

any suggestion please.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But how to do it will depends on how many different products do you have...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some dynamic SQL and Dense_Rank() function

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) 
Select  @SQL = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName(concat('Product',Dense_Rank() over (Order By Product))) 
                                    + ',' + QuoteName(concat('Quantity',Dense_Rank() over (Order By Product))) 
                      From   myTable For XML Path('')),1,1,'')   

Select  @SQL = 'Select Orders,' + @SQL + ' 
                From (
                      Select Orders,Item=concat(''Product'',Dense_Rank() over (Order By Product)),Val=cast(Product as varchar(max)) From myTable
                      Union All
                      Select Orders,Item=concat(''Quantity'',Dense_Rank() over (Order By Product)),Val=cast(Quantity as varchar(max)) From myTable
                     ) A
                Pivot (max(Val) For Item in (' + @SQL + ') ) p'

Exec(@SQL);
```

Returns

```
Orders  Product1    Quantity1   Product2    Quantity2   Product3    Quantity3
100     CUP         1           NULL        NULL        PLATE       2
101     CUP         1           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
102     CUP         2           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
103     CUP         1           GLASS       1           PLATE       3
```